# Need some help binding a model using Gson + Volley

Tags: android, json, gson, android-volley

I'm having some trouble binding json to a model in Android and Volley.

My JSON looks like this:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Zungate/PokemonJSON/master/pokedex.json

My Model looks like this:

```
public class Pokemon
{
private int number;
private String name;
private String type1;
private String type2;
private String imageName;

public Pokemon()
{
}

public Pokemon(int number, String name, String type1, String type2, String imageName)
{
    this.number = number;
    this.name = name;
    this.type1 = type1;
    this.type2 = type2;
    this.imageName = imageName;
}
... Getters not included for brevity
}
```

My Volley and JSON attempt:

String url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Zungate/PokemonJSON/master/pokedex.json";

```
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response)
                {
                    Log.d("response", response);

                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    //List<Pokemon> pokemonList = gson.fromJson(response, new TypeToken<List<Pokemon>>() {}.getType());
                    Pokemon[] pokemonList = gson.fromJson(response, Pokemon[].class);
                    //Log.d("Pokemon", ""+ pokemonList.get(0));
                    Log.d("Pokemon", "Name: "+ pokemonList[0].getName());

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    );

    queue.add(stringRequest);
```

The commented lines are things I've also tried, that also doesn't work. 
I'm probably missing something obvious, but I've looked at this so long, I just don't know anymore.

The response is correct, and the pokemonLIst object correctly has 1889 items. Every items properties are null or 0 however.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after many grey hairs.

It's case sensitive, so I fixed it by adding this:

@SerializedName("NameOfAttribute") to each relevant field in Pokemon.java